# How to pass data from one ng-container to another in Angular Material dynamic table?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am loading data dynamically in an Angular Material table. The table headers are also loaded dynamically. I am adding one static column called "Actions" which contains add, delete and edit operations.
What I want to do is pass the id from the dynamically loaded rows to the Actions column when the edit or delete buttons are clicked.
Is there any way to do this?

The following is my HTML code:

```
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>  
    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns" matColumnDef="{{ column }}"> 
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{column | titlecase}}</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{ row[column] }} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Actions">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="addNew()">
          <mat-icon class="white-icon" aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon">add</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </th>

      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i=index;">
        <button mat-icon-button color="accent" (click)="startEdit(id, teamName)">
          <mat-icon class="purple-icon" aria-label="Edit">edit</mat-icon>
        </button>

        <button mat-icon-button color="accent" (click)="deleteItem(i, row.id, row.title, row.state, row.url)">
          <mat-icon class="purple-icon" aria-label="Delete">delete</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: What data would you like to share?

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more understandable

Comment: in *matCellDef="let row" You have all data of this row, in you method put startEdit(row), or deleteItem(row) on clicking you have data from this row.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can't believe it was that easy!